# Django Serializer from ManyToManyField using through

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to serialize the User model from Django, including a manyToMany relation I created.

Here are my models:

```
class CompanyAccount(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
   user_ids = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='CompanyUser')

class CompanyUser(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, primary_key=True, editable=False)
   user_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   company_id = models.ForeignKey(CompanyAccount, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   is_company_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)
```

Now my goal would be to get the company serialized and returned along with any user.

Here are my serializer, but sadly the company is not returned.

```
class CompanyAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    address_id = AddressSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = CompanyAccount
        fields = '__all__'

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    company_id = CompanyAccountSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'company_id']
```

Any help is welcome :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default related name of a `ManyToManyField` is `modelname_set`, so you can implement this with:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    companyaccount_set = CompanyAccountSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'companyaccount_set']
```

If you want to rename the field, you can use:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    accounts = CompanyAccountSerializer(many=True, read_only=True, source='companyaccount_set')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'accounts']
```

Comment: I receive following error now: Original exception text was: 'ManyRelatedManager' object has no attribute 'address_id'

Comment: @PierreAnken: in your `CompanyAccountSerializer` you specify `address_id` with `many=False`, but apparently this is a one-to-many relation.

Comment: address_id = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
After testing I can't return any field which is a relation without error and nothing is returned when taking a base field from model.

Comment: @PierreAnken: hold on, you should use `many=True` for the `CompanyAccountSerializer`, since it is a `ManyToManyField`..

Comment: BTW you know how I can get back the field is_company_admin in the serializer?

Comment: @PierreAnken: in that case you should make a serializer for the `CompanyUser`, and thus work with `companyuser_set = CompanyUserSerializer(many=True)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239189/discussion-between-pierre-anken-and-willem-van-onsem).